# How to allow users to consume GCP API Gateway programmatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-gateway, idp, google-cloud-api-gateway, google-api-gateway

I have a simple bussiness case, not real one, but common:

1. We have an API to sell, maybe weather API.
2. Users stored and managed with some identity provider.
3. Users can generate JWT token to use for machine-to-machine communication. For example using `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Now what GCP offers for this scenario:

1. [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway) is the way to go, it has [JWT auth](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-jwt) available.
2. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) or [Identity platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/) are good options to store and manage users.
3. Logged in users has JWT which can be used with [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway), but we need machine-to-machine flow to obtain the token. And both [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) or [Identity platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/) can't be used for this.

I am curious if this is a correct way to approach this case, because the only way to solve it is to use some third party identity provider like Auth0, or make inhouse solution to generate machine-to-machine JWT. I just can't believe GCP has nothing to offer for such common use case.

Comment: You can use an Google ID Token that you can generate with a service account. What's the problem with that? https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-googleid

Comment: From the link you send I can see that users can authenticate in a similar manner like with Firebase, again not suitable for machine-to-machine communication. With service account, I have to maintain a custom piece of code to store and generate JWT correct? What I don't like in this approach is that I am not an expert in auth or security, and my code will be vulnerable if I mess up. That's why I prefer managed services.

Comment: You have fallback solution by using API key, but it's not very secure and you have limitation (you can't authenticate account, only GCP projects)